# ul of images only showing first image

Tags: html, css, image

I'm creating a sliding list in jQuery which will move the margin across from a list of images showing one after the other when manually testing moving the image to the left revealing the next the image isn't showing correctly and I can't figure out why. 
Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="slider">
<ul class="pages">
    <li class="page">
        <a href="article.html" >
            <img src="images/iphone-5s2.jpg" alt="an iPhone 5S">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="page">
        <a href="#" >
            <img src"images/network-cables2.jpg" alt="Network cables">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="page">
        <a href="#" >
            <img src"images/black-keyboard2.jpg" alt="Close up of a black keyboard">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
    #slider{
    width:900px;
    height:500px;
    overflow:hidden;
    /*position: relative;
    margin: 0px auto*/
}

#slider .pages {
    display: block;
    width: 5000px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#slider .page {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 900px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of me moving the image across to show the second one not showing properly:![1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdGiz.jpg)

All the images are in the same folder and if I change the order only the first one loads every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is missing `=` after the attribute `src`, so this attribute is ignored and images has no valid source.

```
<img src="images/network-cables2.jpg" alt="Network cables">
<img src="images/black-keyboard2.jpg" alt="Close up of a black keyboard">
       ^^
```